# Sum of values in every other column

Tags: excel, vba

The excel spreadsheet is prepared to create a payment schedule to show current and previous payments. The objective of having the macro is to allow the user to have minimum input to the document, that is, the user inputs are to enter the claim no and the amount of this claim (current claim submitted). Once these information are entered the user runs the macro using the button and depending on the claim number value copied to the respective claim history and summed up to the total and previous payment.
Everything seems working perfect excep if the user runs the macro with out changing the claim no the previous payment and total payment values keep increase. In other words the value in the last claim gets added to the total payment and the claim before the last gets added to the previous payment.
I need help somehow to stop the macro and tell the user the claim no is not changed. This helps to avoid having a wrong total payment and previous payment values.

Example: Lets say claim 1 was $1000 and claim 2 is $2000. If the claim no in B5 is 2 the $2000 in column A (this claim) copied to claim 2 in the claim history. Then the the values $1000 (claim 1)  in the claim history copied to previous payment and both the value ($1000+$2000) in claim 1 and claim 2 in the claim history summed up in the total payment. If the user runs the macro without changing the claim no in Cell B5 2 to 3 both the previous payment increases by $1000 and total payment increase by $2000.

```
Sub SubContractorClaim()

 Dim i As Integer, lastcol As Long, j As Integer, total As Double, lastrow As Long, ClaimNo As 
 Integer, k As Integer, lastrow2 As Long, total2 As Double, WSR As Worksheet, l As Integer

Set WSR = Worksheets("Return of Works")
lastcol = WSR.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 5
lastrow = WSR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = WSR.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
ClaimNo = WSR.Range("B5")


 For i = 12 To lastrow



         For j = 6 To lastcol Step 2



             If WSR.Cells(5, j).Value = ClaimNo Then
             WSR.Cells(i, j).Value = WSR.Cells(i, 1)


             total = WSR.Cells(i, 3)




                If WSR.Cells(5, j).Value <= ClaimNo Then
                total = total + WSR.Cells(i, j)

                End If


                total2 = WSR.Cells(i, 2)

                If ClaimNo > 1 And WSR.Cells(5, j).Value = ClaimNo Then
                total2 = total2 + WSR.Cells(i, j - 2)

                End If


             End If

         Next j

         WSR.Cells(i, 3).Value = total
         WSR.Cells(i, 2).Value = total2

         If WSR.Cells(i, 2) = 0 Then
         WSR.Cells(i, 2) = ""
         End If

         If WSR.Cells(i, 3) = 0 Then
         WSR.Cells(i, 3) = ""
         End If


 Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to check if a value has changed (in your case, "claim no"), you must have somewhere in the worksheet to store the old value because VBA macro run every time anew without storing previous value.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I tried it but I couldn't figure out the link between the stored value and the claim no in cell B5. I think there must be a link between the two values and when the macro runs the stored value also needs to be changed. Unless you have different idea.

Comment: Example, you use B6 to store the previous value. Then, at the beginning of your program, check whether B5 & B6 are the same. If so, perform the actions you want when user didn't change the claim no. Otherwise, perform your calculation and copy the value from B5 to B6.  (using B6 is a simple example. Other options to find some place that is more "hidden" such as a cell on a hidden row, another worksheet or even a VeryHidden worksheet. Or it is a cell with font color = white, which is visually blank)

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the idea. I have managed to stop the macro if the Claim No is not changed.